# which constructor initializes variable x3?

Tags: java, initialization, instance-variables

```
class X {
    int x1, x2, x3;
}

class Y extends X {
    int y1;

    Y() {
        x1 = 1;
        x2 = 2;
        y1 = 10;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Y y = new Y();
        System.out.println(y.x1 + "," + y.x2 + "," + y.x3 + "," + y.y1);
    }
}
```

Which constructor intializes variable x3?

1. default constructor of class `X`
2. default constructor of `Object` class

Comment: What do you think and why?

Comment: x3 is not instantiated

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin fields are always initialized, but not always to values other than default ones.

Comment: which of the two consructors intialize variable x3

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Answer (score 4):

The variable x3 will never be set by any of your constructors. (Your constructors == Y()). It is not set by the Object constructor either, since it doesn't see the fields either

It will get set as 0 by the Virtual Machine at runtime. This behaviour is set this way to remove redundant init code.
See: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=14

Answer (score 0):

You will see its default value.

> As Y extends X, So when you execute **new Y ()**, it will ultimately call no argument constructor of X ( being a super class). Constructor X when called, will initialize state of the class to its default value.